# Python logger with a callback function

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

is there a way to configure a python logger to call a custom function and pass it the logging message whenever it loggs?
Thanks!

Comment: You should look sub classing and implementing your own logging Handler: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#handler-objects and implement the "emit" method where you can do anything you want with the record.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @guy.S Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: @gerrit I've added an answer now (for either Python 2 or 3)

Answer (score 11):

Subclass [`logging.Handler`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#handler-objects) and implement the `emit` method:

```py
import logging

class MyHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        print('custom handler called with\n   ', record)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(MyHandler())   # or: logger.handlers = [MyHandler()]
logger.warning('Log 1')
logger.warning('Log 2')
```

```
custom handler called with
    <LogRecord: __main__, 30, /home/jan/Dropbox/py/so_logging.py, 9, "Log 1">
custom handler called with
    <LogRecord: __main__, 30, /home/jan/Dropbox/py/so_logging.py, 10, "Log 2">
```

The specific message being logged can be accessed as `record.msg` (unformatted string) or `self.format(record)` (formatted string, in case you added a timestamp or loglevel)

Additionally: If you also override the `logging.Handler`'s `__init__` method, it is important to do the super call to it in the subclass.

---

Standard caveats for the `logging` module apply:

- The default loglevel is WARNING (so DEBUG/INFO aren't passed to emit)
- A log record is passed to *all handlers* of a logger

  - After that, it is passed to its ancestor in the [logging hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) recursively