# How do I call a Python function when something is logged

Tags: python, logging

I'm using the logging library and I want to call a function whenever any event is logged. Something like this:

```py
import logging

#logging config here

async def on_log(message, level): #call this whenever something is logged
    print(level, ":", message)

logging.debug("Hello world")
```

Edit: `on_log` is a coroutine

Edit2: I tried implementing one of your suggestions but I'm not 100% sure about how to add it to my current logging configuration.

```py
from logging import *
import datetime
import sys

class MyLogger(Handler):
    def emit(*args):
        for item in args:
            print(item)

time = datetime.datetime.today()
logtime = f"{time.year}-{time.month}-{time.day}__{time.hour}h-{time.minute}m-{time.second}s"

file_handler = FileHandler(filename=f'./logs/{logtime}.log')  # File output
stdout_handler = StreamHandler(sys.stdout)  # Console output

basicConfig(
    format=f'[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s] %(message)s',
    datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
    level=DEBUG,
    handlers=[file_handler, stdout_handler, MyLogger]
)
```

I get this error:
`AttributeError: type object 'MyLogger' has no attribute 'formatter'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write custom python logging handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118059/how-to-write-custom-python-logging-handler)

Comment: This similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354908/python-logger-with-a-callback-function - doesn't currently have an answer but looks like it has a potentially useful comment.

Comment: Add a logging handler to the logging configuration.

Comment: I've taken a look at the other questions, but I still don't really get how to add a custom log handler.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: you have to use `MyLogger` the same way you use `FileHandler` and `StreamHandler` - first you have to create instance `my_handler = MyLogger()` and later use this instance `handlers=[file_handler, stdout_handler, my_handler]`

Answer (score 5):

The comments recommend using a custom handler but I would advise against it since there is a way to do this that is also [proposed in the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) by using filters. In the specific case here it would work like this:

```
import logging

def on_log(record):
    print(record.levelname, ":", record.getMessage())
    return True

logging.root.addFilter(on_log)

logging.warning('some log')
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this when `on_log` is a coroutine?

Answer (score 0):

It is minimal working code

```
import logging

# --- classes ---

class MyLogger():

    #level = logging.NOTSET
    level = logging.DEBUG

    def handle(*args):
        print('--- args ---')
        for item in args:
            print(item)
        print('---')

# --- main ---

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 
#logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) 

my_logger = MyLogger()
#my_logger.level = logging.DEBUG

logger.addHandler(my_logger)

# --- test ---

logger.debug("DEBUG: Hello world")
logger.info("INFO: Hello world")
```

It can't be function but class with method `handle` and in variable `level` because every handler has own level. This way some handlers can be executed always, other only for debug message.

---

**EDIT:**

The same using class [Handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler) which already has variable `level` and you have to only rewrite method `handle`. But is better to rewrite method `emit` which is executed by `handle` after filtering.

You can set level when you create instance.

```
import logging

# --- classes ---

class MyLogger(logging.Handler):
    
    #def handle(*args):
    def emit(*args):
        print('--- args ---')
        for item in args:
            print(item)
        print('---')
        
# --- main ---

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 
#logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) 

my_logger = MyLogger(logging.DEBUG)

logger.addHandler(my_logger)

# --- test ---

logger.debug("DEBUG: Hello world")
logger.info("INFO: Hello world")
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how to add add this to my current logging configuration (I edited the post)